# Turn on VPN Pass-through at WR340G

Tags: wireless-router

I have router WR340G v3 0815311C, but I can't find VPN Pass-through option, but I must find it because without it I can't connect via Zywall to my company internet.

Has anybody the same problem?

Comment: Strange, it says it supports it...damned if I can find it in the user manual, maybe virtual server?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get answer from tp-link support:

This router supports VPN passthrough, but there is no option(switch) to enable/disable it.
This function is enabled all the time on the router, and we are not able to disable it.

So now I don't know what is a source of my problem :/

I'll make another question